# Export Value from Mongoose find function in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, crud

I am trying to build a app using nodejs. I am using Mongoose to create and read from database . I am able to read from collection using find() but I can not use the data out of the find() function. When I try to use the data outside the function it shows undefined. Can someone help me and share how I can export data from find() function.

```
  var importantData;

    Important.find(function(err,data){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            importantData = data;
         
        }
    })

    console.log(importantData)
```

Comment: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to save the `.find()` query result for later use. The first is using .then(), the second is using async/await. Either way, don't forget to add error handling!

### Using .then()

```
let importantData

Important.find({})
  .then((data) => {
    console.log("Important Data found! ", data)
    importantData = data
    // now data is accessible from outside the then block
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

### Using async/await

```
// Don't forget the try/catch block if you use Async/Await!
try {
  const importantData = await Important.find({})

  console.log("Important Data found! ", importantData)
} catch (exception) {
  console.log(exception)
}
```